# Python3 out of source build

Tags: python, python-3.x, setuptools, python-wheel

**What I want**

Put all build output generated (`build`, `dist`, `my_package.egg_info`, etc) by `python setup.py` into a specific directory.

**Project structure**

```
awesome_pkg/
    __init__.py
    mod.py
my_fancy_app/
   __init__.py
   __main__.py
target/
requirements.txt
setup.py
```

`__main__.py`:

```
def main():
    print("Hello virtual environment")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

`setup.py`:

```
import setuptools

setuptools.setup(
        name = "my_fancy_app",
        version="0.0.1",
        author="Me Myself",
        author_email="me@my.self",
        description="Some description",
        long_description="Some long description",
        packages=setuptools.find_packages(),
        entry_points={
            'console_scripts': [ 'hlpth = my_fancy_app.__main__:main' ]
        },
        classifiers=[
            "Programming Language :: Python :: 3.7",
            "License :: OSI Approved :: MIT License",
            "Operating System :: OS Independent",
        ],
        python_requires='>=3.7'
)
```

`__init__.py` is an empty script

---

**What I tried**

I tried to simply run `setup.py` with a specific working directory:

```
cd target
python3.7 ../setup.py bdist_wheel
```

**The problem**

The problem is it does not really package anything:

```
$ python3.7 ../setup.py bdist_wheel 
running bdist_wheel                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
running build                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
installing to build/bdist.linux-x86_64/wheel                                                                                                                                                                                           
running install                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
running install_egg_info                                                                                                                                                                                                               
running egg_info                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
creating my_fancy_app.egg-info                                                                                                                                                                                                         
writing my_fancy_app.egg-info/PKG-INFO                                                                                                                                                                                                 
writing dependency_links to my_fancy_app.egg-info/dependency_links.txt                                                                                                                                                                 
writing entry points to my_fancy_app.egg-info/entry_points.txt                                                                                                                                                                         
writing top-level names to my_fancy_app.egg-info/top_level.txt                                                                                                                                                                         
writing manifest file 'my_fancy_app.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'                                                                                                                                                                              
reading manifest file 'my_fancy_app.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'                                                                                                                                                                              
writing manifest file 'my_fancy_app.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'                                                                                                                                                                              
Copying my_fancy_app.egg-info to build/bdist.linux-x86_64/wheel/my_fancy_app-0.0.1-py3.7.egg-info                                                                                                                                      
running install_scripts                                                                                                                                                                                                                
creating build/bdist.linux-x86_64/wheel/my_fancy_app-0.0.1.dist-info/WHEEL                                                                                                                                                             
creating 'dist/my_fancy_app-0.0.1-py3-none-any.whl' and adding 'build/bdist.linux-x86_64/wheel' to it                                                                                                                                  
adding 'my_fancy_app-0.0.1.dist-info/METADATA'                                                                                                                                                                                         
adding 'my_fancy_app-0.0.1.dist-info/WHEEL'                                                                                                                                                                                            
adding 'my_fancy_app-0.0.1.dist-info/entry_points.txt'                                                                                                                                                                                 
adding 'my_fancy_app-0.0.1.dist-info/top_level.txt'                                                                                                                                                                                    
adding 'my_fancy_app-0.0.1.dist-info/RECORD'                                                                                                                                                                                           
removing build/bdist.linux-x86_64/wheel
```

But running it from the source root directory works perfectly fine `python3.7 setup.py bdist_wheel` and both of the packages are bundled into the `wheel` archive.

Is there a way to do such out of source build?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will have to play around until you find the right combination of *setuptools* commands and options for your exact use case. For example I have had some success with the following combination for a `bdist_wheel`:

```
python3 setup.py egg_info --egg-base target build --build-base target/build bdist_wheel --dist-dir target/dist
```

Comment: Works exactly the way I wanted. Thanks. But the question is that out-of-source build is a pretty common task. Why does it require relatively complicated solution like this?

Comment: The authors and maintainers of _setuptools_ probably didn't consider this use case. Personally, I have never needed this either. Maybe some other Python packaging tools offer an easier way to do this.

Answer (score 2):

You can specify the output directory for each build type as follows:

```
python setup.py sdist -d target/ bdist -d target/ bdist_wheel -d target/
```

To get rid of any temporary `build` etc dirs/files created during the build, run the following afterwards:

```
python setup.py clean --all
```

Note, it is generally safest to run `setup.py` from the directory it is in. Internally it may have relative paths referencing things like src, libs etc, and this will break if you are in a different location while running.

Comment: Yes it works, but not exactly the way I expected.  Precisely I ran `python3.7 setup.py bdist_wheel -d target/`, but `build/` and `my_fancy_app.egg_info/` were still created at source root (`dist/` was not emitted anymore). The `target/` contains only the `wheel` archive.

Comment: `bdist_wheel` calls the other types implicitly. If you need them as well, then add them to the list, with their own `-d`. I've updated the answer to reflect this.

Comment: The `build/` and `my_fancy_app.egg_info/` still get created if building this way. I ran `python3.7 setup.py sdist -d target/ bdist -d target/ bdist_wheel -d target/`, the `target/` dir now contains 2 `.tar.gz` archives along with the `whl` one.

Comment: Added some more info about `clean`